# Foundation Zurb Select List in Reveal Modal losing style

Tags: select, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation, html-select

I am looking at including a select list within a reveal modal window. I would like the custom forms styling to apply to the element but it appears to break when the element is within a reveal modal element. You see the original select list and underneath that the UL element it generates to replace it (without any styling applied)

```
<div id="divX" class="reveal-modal">

    <div class="large-4 columns">
      <label for="customDropdown1">Medium Example</label>
      <select id="customDropdown1" class="medium">
        <option DISABLED>This is a dropdown</option>
        <option>This is another option</option>
        <option>This is another option too</option>
        <option>Look, a third option</option>
      </select>
    </div>

</div>
```

I do have the class="custom" attribute on the form tag. When the select list is placed on the page outside of the reveal modal div it appears fine.

-Just to note I am using the latest Foundation 4.3.2 revision and the issue appears on both IE and Chrome. I have turned on script debugging and there are no errors reported.

Comment: Custom form styling is issue prone, could be a number of things. If you want assistance, I'd suggest becoming a registered user, then creating a working jsfiddle and adding the link to your post.

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for that I will look into it. I have found a workaround (other than using radio buttons in place of) in that on reveal open I dynamically wrap the select element in a form tag.

Comment: I recently updated the project to Foundation 5, the issue no longer exists on Chrome. With IE the styling of select lists appears broken regardless of position in document/within reveal modal

Answer (score 1):

Zurb suggests putting the modal code at the very bottom of your html markup, directly above the /body tag.

This breaks certain functions due to zurb calling all scripts immediately before that. If you put your modal code above the script calls they will function properly.

Consider using jquery to load the scripts upon the document completion rather than calling everything at the end of the page to make your markup cleaner and less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#myZurbModal").foundation('reveal', {
            opened: function () {
                $(this).appendTo("form");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more explanation than just the code? thx

Comment: Thank you, I was looking everywhere for this...
Little explanation for damienfrancois: this code runs the function whenever a modal is revealed(opened), the function being the `$(this).appendTo("form")` in this case.